# Sort/Merge without cursor

Tags: sql-server, sorting, cursor

Without using a cursor, I am trying to come up with T-SQL code that would accomplish the following:

On the following table,

```
SourceData
```

that has two columns, `[ColA]` and `[ColB]`, where both are `nvarchar(255)`, with the following example data:

```
ColA    |  ColB
==================
AAA     |  TripleA
TripleA |  AAA
AAA     |  ThreeAs
ThreeAs |  AAA
BBB     |  TripleB
TripleB |  BBB
BBB     |  ThreeBs
ThreeBs |  BBB
```

etc.,

extract the row data into TWO tables,

`TableA_Root`, and `TableB_Children`

Where `TableA_Root` has these columns: `[ROID identity], [Root]`

and `TableB_Children` has these columns: `[COID identity],[fKey_ROID],[Child]`

Such that the resulting table has the example data as such:

```
TableA_Root
==============
1  |  AAA
2  |  BBB

TableB_Children
===============
1 | 1 | TripleA
2 | 1 | ThreeAs
3 | 2 | TripleB
4 | 2 | ThreeBs
```

At first, I thought I would use a Cursor.  But, that is not the optimal approach, I am sure.  Obviously, this is a sort and merge, which I could do outside of SQL.  Some of the ideas I have tried with subqueries using "IN" or "EXISTS" but my attempts are falling short.  I could use a fresh perspective.

Comment: How do you know that `AAA` is in the Root and not the Children table?

Comment: Given these two rows `{AAA,TripleA}`,`{TripleA, AAA}` how can you identify 'AAA' as the root and not TripleA?

Comment: That is an excellent question.  If I were approaching this via a cursor, I would make the assumption that the first occurrence of the tuple dictates the root because it occurred first in ColA.  This is one of the reasons I have been struggling with a non-cursor idea.  I thought perhaps I convert the source table so that it has an identity column with its unique key, so that I could do some manner of comparison in order to make that choice.

Comment: oh I was hoping root could be defined as anything that existed more than once in ColB. First in the table is a little dangerous because without an order by order isn't guaranteed

Comment: Perhaps the root datum could be "chosen" by comparing ColA with ColB and selecting that datum that is "less-than" the other.  In this data, it is not important that either be selected as the root.

Comment: There is no guarantee that ColB will contain more than one instance of each flip-flop pair.  There are some instances where there is exactly two records, each a reversal of the other.  Then, there are many rows where there are "duplicates" of what could be a "root".

Comment: Well here's [a solution](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2a391/23) that uses the assumption that I mentioned. Note for some reason sql fiddle won't output both results but it would work in SSMS

Comment: Conrad: thank you for both the SQL code, as well as for introducing me to the Fiddle.  Nice to have an alternative tool to play around with.

Comment: @NW7US yeah fiddle is awesome. BTW if you put an `@` in front of my name I would have been notified via the inbox. See [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/148672)

Comment: @ConradFrix - I am so glad to have joined the community.  This rocks.  Thank you for the pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is a primary key on SourceData where you can't have duplicates of the same row then this would get you what you want...

```
With    cte1 As
(
        Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By ph) As ph, 
                ColA, 
                ColB
        From   (Select  1 As ph, 
                        ColA,
                        ColB
                From    SourceData) As n
)
Insert  TableA_Root (ROID, Root)
Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By c.ph) As ROID,
        ColA
From    cte1 c
Where   Not Exists (Select  1
                    From    cte1 c2
                    Where   c.ColA = c2.ColB
                    And     c.ph > c2.ph);

Insert  TableB_Children (COID, ROID, Child)
Select  Row_Number() Over (Order By ta.ROID), 
        ta.ROID, 
        tb.Colb
From    TableA_Root ta
Join    SourceData tb
        On  ta.Root = tb.ColA;
```

Comment: Very clever: using the **Row_Number** to create the OIDs needed.  I figured that I would have some sort of **aOID > bOID** comparison.  I just could not quite get there.  After using this technique, I did discover some new characteristics in my source data, but, with these results, I can now move forward to the final form (which is an XML thesaurus which will be included in my MSSQL 2012 database for use with the CONTAINS...FORMSOF  -- Thank you very much for your time and energy on this.

Comment: By the way: I realized that, in my original post, I mixed metaphors. Root should have Leaf Nodes, and Children should have Parent.

Comment: I think you're missing `INTO` after the `INSERT`. Also if you want to avoid the `SELECT 1 as ph` and the inline view `n` you can do `ROW_NUMBER OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))` [See here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85381/4)

Comment: That's pretty nifty. I didn't know you could get away with that in the Row_Number() Order By. Pretty cool. The "Into" after Insert is optional. It's more for readability than execution. I always leave it out due to laziness.